# Issue on IE when deploying from VS to IIS, but fine on azure?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

I'm having an issue when deploying to IIS 6.1 from VS2012, it does not render properly on IE.

http://www.lasereyeinstitute.com/home

compare to:

http://leibeta.azurewebsites.net/home

Ive checked to ensure all the files are included in the package. Could it be a setting in IIS? I would factor out a cross browser issue as it renders correctly when debugging locally on IISExpress, and on azure?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue, hopefully it helps someone else...

We are on an active directory domain, and there was a GPO setting "Display intranet sites in compatibility mode", and although our IP for the website is external, it matched the host name and was turning on compatibility mode. Disabling this resolved the issue.